# Synchronization of send() and recv() methods while using sockets

Tags: python, c++, sockets, networking, server

I'm making a C++ server and a Python client that will play the game of Hangman. My idea is that the programs communicate via TCP sockets (`send()`/`recv()` methods).

My server is written in C++, and it first creates a socket and binds it to the address and port. Then it listens for client connections. Every time a client connects, the server accepts the connection and creates a new thread that will handle that client's game by calling the `hangmanGame()` function.

The `hangmanGame()` function is very simple. It first chooses a random word to be an answer, and creates a "guessing" string full of `_` signs for the answer. Then, it sends that guessing string to the client using `send()`. Then, the server receives a letter from the client using `recv()`. That letter then goes through validation (to see if the user entered a valid letter, and not an empty string, more letters, a letter he guessed before or something that's not a letter, etc). Then the server checks if the letter is guessed and returns a message (via `send()`) to the client.

This is my server code:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

const int PORT = 8000;
const int MAX_CLIENTS = 8;

void *hangmanGame(void *arg)
{
    int client_socket = *(int *)arg;
    int lives = 5;
    string names[10] = {
        "anastasia",
        "andrew",
        "bradley",
        "bonnie",
        "christian",
        "fiona",
        "george",
        "oliver",
        "gladys",
        "pamela"};

    // setting the random generator with current time
    // so its a different random number each time the program runs
    srand(time(0));
    int randomNum = rand() % (sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]));

    // pick an answer randomly
    string answer = names[randomNum];
    int answerLength = answer.length();

    // initialize the guessing string
    string guessing;
    for (int i = 0; i < answerLength; i++)
    {
        guessing += "_";
    }

    const char *message;
    char buffer[1024];
    string letter;
    string tempMessage;

    // game loop
    while (lives > 0 && guessing != answer)
    {
        bzero(buffer, 1024);
        int status = send(client_socket, guessing.c_str(), strlen(guessing.c_str()), 0);
        if (status < 0)
        {
            cout << "Error: Failed to send guessing string to client" << endl;
            close(client_socket);
            return NULL;
        }

        status = recv(client_socket, buffer, 1024, 0);
        if (status == -1)
        {
            cout << "Error: Failed to recieve data from client\n"
                 << endl;
            close(client_socket);
            return NULL;
        }
        letter = buffer[0];

        // check if the user entered an empty string
        if (letter.length() == 0)
        {
            message = "You didn't enter anything. Please enter a letter.\n";
            send(client_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
            cout << "Client entered empty string\n";
            continue;
        }

        // check if the user entered multiple characters
        if (letter.length() > 1)
        {
            message = "You entered multiple characters. Please enter only one letter.\n";
            send(client_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
            cout << "Client entered multiple characters\n";
            continue;
        }

        // check if the user entered a letter
        if (!isalpha(letter[0]))
        {
            message = "Please enter a letter.\n";
            send(client_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
            cout << "Client didn't enter a letter\n";
            continue;
        }

        letter = tolower(letter[0]);
        // check if user has already guessed this letter
        if (guessing.find(letter) != string::npos)
        {
            message = "You already guessed this letter. Try again.\n";
            send(client_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
            cout << "Client has already guessed this letter\n";
            continue;
        }

        // compare every letter of the answer to user's input letter
        bool found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < answerLength; i++)
        {
            if (answer[i] == letter[0])
            {
                guessing[i] = letter[0];
                found = true;
            }
        }

        // if the letter is incorrect, take 1 life
        if (!found)
        {
            --lives;
            if (lives == 0)
            {
                tempMessage = "Game over. You failed to guess the answer - " + answer + "!\n";
                message = tempMessage.c_str();
                send(client_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
                cout << "Client lost all lives\n";
                close(client_socket);
            }
            else
            {
                tempMessage = "Incorrect. You have " + to_string(lives) + " lives left.\n";
                message = tempMessage.c_str();
                send(client_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
                cout << "Client guessed wrong and lost a life\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (guessing == answer)
            {
                tempMessage = "You guessed the answer - " + answer + "!\n";
                message = tempMessage.c_str();
                send(client_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
                cout << "Client won\n";
                close(client_socket);
            }
            else
            {
                tempMessage = "Correct! You have " + to_string(lives) + " lives left.\n";
                message = tempMessage.c_str();
                send(client_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
                cout << "Client guessed the right letter\n";
            }
        }
    }

    close(client_socket);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int server_socket, client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    pthread_t thread_id;

    // Creating the server socket
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket == -1)
    {
        cout << "Error creating server socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Server socket created" << endl;

    // Set the server address and port
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Bind the server socket to the address and port
    if (::bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
    {
        cout << "Error binding server socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Server socket bind complete" << endl;

    // Listening on the server socket
    if (listen(server_socket, MAX_CLIENTS) == -1)
    {
        cout << "Error listening for clients on server socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Listening..." << endl;

    // Accepting client connections as they come in, and creating a new thread for each client
    while (true)
    {
        socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client_addr);
        client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_len);
        if (client_socket == -1)
        {
            cout << "Error accepting client connection" << endl;
            close(client_socket);
            exit(1);
        }
        cout << "Accepted client" << endl;

        // Creating a new thread and starting the game for each client
        if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, hangmanGame, (void *)&client_socket) != 0)
        {
            cout << "Error creating new thread" << endl;
            close(client_socket);
            exit(1);
        }
        cout << "Thread for client created" << endl;
        pthread_detach(thread_id);
    }

    close(server_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

The client is written in Python. It first connects to the server, and then goes into a `while` loop. Inside the `while` loop, the client first receives the "guessing" string so the user can see how many letters the answer has. Then the client asks the user to enter a letter, and sends that letter to the server. The server does its thing and returns a message that will be received from the client side. Only if the message is a final one ("You guessed..." or "Game over...") the `while` loop will end because the game ended.

Here is the code for my client:

```py
import socket

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8000

print("Welcome to HANGMAN!")

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    # Receive the guessing board from the server
    board = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(board)

    # Get the letter from the user and send it to the server
    letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
    client_socket.send(letter.encode() + b"\n")

    # Recieve the message from the server
    status = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(status)

    # If the message is a final one (win/lose), end the game
    if(status.startswith("You guessed")): 
        break
    elif(status.startswith("Game over.")):
        break
    else:
        continue

client_socket.close()
```

However, I have a problem.

Whenever I start the game, my server successfully starts to listen, and my client manages to connect to the server. Then, I get the guessing string (board) and the client prints it out. It asks me for a letter and I send it. The server does its thing and sends back a message, and I get it printed out on the client side. The `while` loops on the client and server side starts up again (2nd iteration) and I get the new, updated guessing string.

However, the client does not ask me for a new letter. It just freezes. When I kill the server, only **then** the client asks me for a new letter. And if I kill the client before the server, the server acts as if I kept repeatedly guessing that first letter.

How do I fix this?

Comment: With your first code block, why does the function return a void* if it always returns null anyway? Void* is a generic pointer to pretty much any type, if you removed the * you would not need to return anything.

Comment: 1) There is no correlation between `send` and `receive` calls – TCP/IP is an unstructured stream of octets. If you want any "call/response" structure, you need to implement that protocol yourself on top. 2) `letter = buffer[0];` creates a one-character string. There is no point in checking its length. 3) There are probably more issues.

Comment: There are several simple ways to send messages. (1) Prefix-length. Send the N (length of the message) as a fixed-size integer in network byte order, then send N bytes of the message. Receive a fixed-size integer in network byte order, then receive that many bytes of the message. (2) Message terminator. Send all messages as null-terminated C strings. Receive byte by byte until a null terminator is seen.

Comment: There's a lot of code here.  Start with a simple proof-of-concept program that can send and receive messages, since this is the hardest thing to get right.  Once that is working reliably, move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a byte stream.  It has no concept of messages, there is no 1:1 relationship between sends and reads, like there is in UDP.  Your code is sending arbitrary bytes back and forth without any real structure to them.

For instance, whenever your server sends a string message to a client, it is not telling that client how large that string actually is, so the client has no way to know when to stop reading the string.  That is the root of your freezing issue on the client side.

So, you need to design your messages in a way that allows the receiver to detect the end of a string has been received.  There are only 2 ways to do that in TCP, which @n.m. mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75734033/synchronization-of-send-and-recv-methods-while-using-sockets#comment133601598_75734033):

> There are several simple ways to send messages.
>
> (1) Prefix-length. Send the N (length of the message) as a fixed-size integer in network byte order, then send N bytes of the message. Receive a fixed-size integer in network byte order, then receive that many bytes of the message.
>
> (2) Message terminator. Send all messages as null-terminated C strings. Receive byte by byte until a null terminator is seen.

When your client sends a `letter` to the server, it is sending a `\n` terminator afterwards (#2 above), which is good, except that your server code is not looking for that terminator at all.  It simply asks `recv()` to read an arbitrary block of 1024 bytes, and `recv()` will return whatever bytes it has available at that moment, up to 1024 bytes max.  The client is likewise doing the same thing when reading messages from the server.

Also, there are some other problems in your codes:

- your server is not handing the case where a client disconnects "gracefully", which is why your server acts incorrectly when you kill the client.  When a client disconnects "gracefeully", `recv()` will return 0, not -1.  But you are not handling that case at all, so you end up processing the previous `buffer` data over and over.
- your server has a race condition when starting a `hangmanGame()` thread. You are reusing a single variable to accept each new client socket. When a new client is accepted, you are passing a pointer to that variable to `pthread_create()`, and then you immediately go back to waiting for a new client.  As such, there is a small window of oppurtunity where your accept loop *might* accept a new client, thus updating the variable, before the previously created thread has had a chance to start running and read that variable.  So, you need to pass the variable in a more thread-safe manner, such as passing in the *value* of the variable rather than a *pointer* to the variable.  In which case, since you are clearly using C++11 or later (as evident by your use of `std::to_string()`) then you should be using the standard `std::thread` class instead of the pthreads library directly.
- both server and client are not accounting for the fact that `send()` and `recv()` can (and frequently do) return fewer bytes than requested.  So, you need to call them both in a loop to ensure that all expected bytes have actually been sent/received.
- your server is calling `srand()` every time a new client is accepted.  It should be calling that only one time, such as at program startup.  Or better, simply stop using a C-style RNG (`rand()`) at all, and instead use a C++-style RNG, such as `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

With all of that said, try something more like the following:

Server:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdint>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

using namespace std;

const int PORT = 8000;
const int MAX_CLIENTS = 8;

ssize_t readRawFromClient(int client_socket, void *data, size_t data_size)
{
    char* pdata = reinterpret_cast<char*>(data);
    while (data_size > 0)
    {
        ssize_t recvd = recv(client_socket, pdata, data_size, 0);
        if (recvd <= 0)
            return recvd;
        pdata += recvd;
        data_size -= recvd;
    }
    return 1;
}

ssize_t readMessageFromClient(int client_socket, string &msg)
{
    msg.clear();
    char ch;
    while (readRawFromClient(client_socket, &ch, 1) > 0)
    {
        if (ch == '\0')
            return true;
        msg += ch;
    }
    return false;
}

bool sendRawToClient(int client_socket, const void *data, size_t data_size)
{
    const char* pdata = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data);
    while (data_size > 0)
    {
        ssize_t sent = send(client_socket, pdata, data_size, 0);
        if (sent <= 0)
            return false;
        pdata += sent;
        data_size -= sent;
    }
    return true;
}

bool sendMessageToClient(int client_socket, const string &msg)
{
    return sendRawToClient(client_socket, msg.c_str(), msg.size() + 1);
}

void hangmanGame(int client_socket)
{
    int lives = 5;

    const string names[10] = {
        "anastasia",
        "andrew",
        "bradley",
        "bonnie",
        "christian",
        "fiona",
        "george",
        "oliver",
        "gladys",
        "pamela"};

    // TODO: you really should be using a C++-based RNG instead...
    int randomNum = rand() % (sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]));

    // pick an answer randomly
    string answer = names[randomNum];
    int answerLength = answer.size();

    // initialize the guessing string
    string guessing(answerLength, '_');

    string clientInput;
    char letter;
    ssize_t recvd;

    // game loop
    do
    {
        if (!sendMessageToClient(client_socket, guessing))
        {
            cout << "Error: Failed to send guessing string to client" << endl;
            break;
        }

        if ((recvd = readMessageFromClient(client_socket, clientInput)) <= 0)
        {
            if (recvd == 0)
                cout << "Client disconnected" << endl;
            else
                cout << "Error: Failed to receive data from client" << endl;
            break;
        }

        // check if the user entered an empty string
        if (clientInput.empty())
        {
            sendMessageToClient(client_socket, "You didn't enter anything. Please enter a letter.");
            cout << "Client entered empty string\n";
            continue;
        }

        // check if the user entered multiple characters
        if (clientInput.size() > 1)
        {
            sendMessageToClient(client_socket, "You entered multiple characters. Please enter only one letter.");
            cout << "Client entered multiple characters\n";
            continue;
        }

        letter = clientInput[0];

        // check if the user entered an alphabet letter
        if (!isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(letter)))
        {
            sendMessageToClient(client_socket, "Please enter a letter.");
            cout << "Client didn't enter a letter\n";
            continue;
        }

        letter = static_cast<char>(tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(letter)));

        // check if user has already guessed this letter
        if (guessing.find(letter) != string::npos)
        {
            sendMessageToClient(client_socket, "You already guessed this letter. Try again.");
            cout << "Client has already guessed this letter\n";
            continue;
        }

        // compare every letter of the answer to user's input letter
        bool found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < answerLength; ++i)
        {
            if (answer[i] == letter)
            {
                guessing[i] = letter;
                found = true;
            }
        }

        // if the letter is incorrect, take 1 life
        if (!found)
        {
            --lives;
            if (lives == 0)
            {
                sendMessageToClient(client_socket, "Game over. You failed to guess the answer - " + answer + "!");
                cout << "Client lost all lives\n";
                break;
            }

            sendMessageToClient(client_socket, "Incorrect. You have " + to_string(lives) + " lives left.");
            cout << "Client guessed wrong and lost a life\n";
        }
        else if (guessing == answer)
        {
            sendMessageToClient(client_socket, "You guessed the answer - " + answer + "!");
            cout << "Client won\n";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            sendMessageToClient(client_socket, "Correct! You have " + to_string(lives) + " lives left.");
            cout << "Client guessed the right letter\n";
        }
    }
    while (true);

    close(client_socket);
}

int main()
{
    // setting the random generator with current time
    // so its a different random number each time the program runs
    srand(time(0));

    int server_socket, client_socket;
    sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    pthread_t thread_id;

    // Creating the server socket
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error creating server socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Server socket created" << endl;

    // Set the server address and port
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Bind the server socket to the address and port
    if (::bind(server_socket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&server_addr), sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error binding server socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Server socket bind complete" << endl;

    // Listening on the server socket
    if (listen(server_socket, MAX_CLIENTS) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error listening for clients on server socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Listening..." << endl;

    // Accepting client connections as they come in, and creating a new thread for each client
    while (true)
    {
        socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client_addr);
        client_socket = accept(server_socket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&client_addr), &client_len);
        if (client_socket < 0)
        {
            cout << "Error accepting client connection" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        cout << "Accepted client" << endl;

        // Creating a new thread and starting the game for each client
        try
        {
            thread(hangmanGame, client_socket).detach();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            cout << "Error creating new thread" << endl;
            close(client_socket);
            return 1;
        }

        cout << "Thread for client created" << endl;
    }

    close(server_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```py
import socket

def sendMessageToServer(sckt, msg):
    buffer = msg.encode() + b'\0'
    totalsent = 0
    while totalsent < len(buffer):
        sent = sckt.send(buffer[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        totalsent = totalsent + sent

def receiveMessageFromServer(sckt):
    chars = []
    while True:
        c = sckt.recv(1)
        if c == b'':
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        if c == chr(0):
            return b''.join(chars).decode()
        chars.append(c)
    
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8000

print("Welcome to HANGMAN!")

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    # Receive the guessing board from the server
    board = receiveMessageFromServer(client_socket)
    print(board)

    # Get the letter from the user and send it to the server
    letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
    sendMessageToServer(client_socket, letter)

    # Receive the message from the server
    status = receiveMessageFromServer(client_socket)
    print(status)

    # If the message is a final one (win/lose), end the game
    if(status.startswith("You guessed")): 
        break
    elif(status.startswith("Game over.")):
        break
    else:
        continue

client_socket.close()
```